# C# query and comparing entries in a CSV file

Tags: c#, linq

I have to compare entries from a csv file that might contain more than 100000 entries and find pairs and store them in another file.
The comparison has to check values in two or more columns for instance:

Dogs    5

Cats    7

Mice    5

Dogs    3

Dogs    5

In this example I have to pick up the pair {Dogs, 5} and ignore the rest.
What approach would you suggest?

Thanks as usual

Comment: Not enough info. Do you always pick only one? How do you choose?

Comment: How do you pick - by number of occurrence or by some other criterion?

Comment: I'll pick all the ones that are repeated and put them in another files, they might have other values in the other columns that I might need to see later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your schema is really this simply, it could be accomplished in a minimal amount of code using [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387036.aspx) and [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

The basic strategy in any case is to create a data structure to track what you have seen and use that to determine what to output. A dictionary tracking counts could be used as well. However, as a means of memory versus code trade-off, I've chosen to use two sets instead of one dictionary:

```
// 1. Data structure to track items we've seen
var found = new HashSet<Tuple<string, int>>();

// 2. Data structure to track items we should output
var output = new HashSet<Tuple<string, int>>();

// 3. Loop over the input data, storing it into `found`
using (var input = File.OpenText(path))
{
    string line;
    while (null != (line = input.ReadLine()))
    {
        // 4. Do your CSV parsing
        var parts = line.Split(','); // <- need better CSV parsing
        var item = Tuple.Create(parts[0], Int32.Parse(parts[1]));

        // 5. Track items we've found and those we should output
        // NB: HashSet.Add returns `false` if it already exists,
        // so we use that as our criteria to mark the item for output
        if (!found.Add(item)) output.Add(item);
    }
}

// 6. Output the items
// NB: you could put this in the main loop and borrow the same strategy
// we used for `found` to determine when to output an item so that only
// one pass is needed to read and write the data.
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact specifics, the first step I would take is looking into a Linq To CVS library, such as this...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library